# What does this podio error mean and how do i resolve it?

Tags: podio

I am trying to update an item on podio through their Java API. It worked fine for a while, but now, but after some time it gave me this error:

```
 APIException [status=Conflict, error=conflict, description=A newer version exists , parameters=null]
```

Right now, if I sent another request to update the item that had this error, it will return the same error. I don't understand.
What does this error mean? and how do i solve it? Is that item going to give me the same error error forever?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
List<FieldValuesUpdate> fields = new ArrayList<>();
String valueSubId = "value";
fields.add(new FieldValuesUpdate(1234567890, valueSubId, something.getName()));
fields.add(new FieldValuesUpdate(1234567891, valueSubId, something.getCode()));
fields.add(new FieldValuesUpdate(1234567892, valueSubId, something.getAddress()));
fields.add(new FieldValuesUpdate(1234567893, valueSubId, something.getStatus()));

ItemUpdate itemUpdate = new ItemUpdate(null, fields);

int itemId = 123444;
podioItemApi.updateItem(itemId, itemUpdate, true, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create item and adding fields but your app is updated and maybe some of fields doesn't exist anymore.

Please send full http request and response for your call, that will definitely help understanding what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't add new fields. I notice this happens when I close the app, open it again, then send another update request. This also happens when someone tries to update the item in podio, then I send an update request through the app. I found out that the only way to resolve this is to set the revision number +1 in the update request. Which is weird because the docs says the revision number is OPTIONAL. Why i have to set it everytime, really bothers me. Is there a way to just let it succeed in updating? Right now we just store the revision number in our database to save

Comment: on rate limits.

Comment: As far as I know, you don't have to provide revision number. What happens when you don't send it? Also, can yo update your question to include **ALL** fields that are set?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue as well.
And as mentioned earlier, it has to do with the revision provided. Using the Java API, the revision is set automatically. Therefore, if an entry has been updated manually it will have a revision of >0, while example by JayDoe will leave it at 0 which is the conflict.

I decided not to hack the API, but use it the way an update workflow is meant to be used. reading the entry first, then setting its revision into the ItemUpdate object.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did try to do a GET request first, getting the revision number and setting it to ItemUpdate object and it worked, however that's another point removed from the rate limit, which is why I stored the revision number in our database instead and used that every time there is an update. Have you also noticed that this error happens when the app is killed and ran again (even if the item on podio isn't changed)? Wonder what's causing it.